# Scalar Curvature Bound along Ricci Flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I have a question when reading Bennett Chow's book "The Ricci Flow: An Introduction."

The lemma 6.67 (in the page 219) in the book says that by the equation (6.6) (in the page 176), which asserts along the Ricci flow on a compact manifold, 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R=\Delta R+2|Ric|^2$$
where $R$ and $Ric$ are scalar and Ricci curvature at time $t,$ we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R\ge \Delta R$$
along the "normalized" Ricci flow. This seems nonsense to me since at the previous page (218) there claims that along the normalized Ricci flow we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}R=\Delta R+2|Ric|^2-rR$$
where $r$ is the average of $R$ on the manifold at time $t,$ and I don't understand why we can derive
$$2|Ric|^2-rR\ge 0.$$

In Hamilton's original paper "Three-manifolds with positive Ricci curvature," he treated this by Klingenber's theorem, so I got surprised when seeing that Chow could solve this just by maximum principle.

Any advice is welcome and thanks in advance!

Comment: There may be a typo in Chow's book. You should look at Hamilton's article "Three-orbifolds with positive Ricci curvature" which you can find in "Collected papers on Ricci flow" edited by Cao, Chow, Chu, and Yau. It reproves Hamilton's original paper without the use of the Klingenberg estimate.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to find it out!